# Directive not loading in angular view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am a newbie to angular.
I have an index.html file and controller.js file as follows
`

```
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="controller.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-app="testApp">

  <div ng-controller="appCtrl">
    Sample 1 :a ={{a}}</br>
    Sample 1:b ={{b}}</br>
    <input ng-model="a">
    <hr>
    <div ng-controller="childCtrl">
      Sample 2: a ={{a}}</br>
      <input ng-model="a"></br>
      Sample 2 :b ={{b}}</br>
      Sample 2: c ={{c}}</br>
      Sample 2 :d ={{d}}</br>
      <hr>
    </div>
    <div message></div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

`
And this is controller.js

```
    var app = angular.module("testApp", []);

app.controller("appCtrl", function($scope) {

  $scope.a = 10;
  $scope.b = 20;
});



 app.controller("childCtrl", function($scope) {

  $scope.c = 30;
  $scope.d = 40;
});
    app.directive("message", function() {
      return {
        templateUrl: 'test.html',
        restrict: 'A'
      };
    });
```

I am trying to add a directive template from file test.html with markup

```
  <h1>Hi</h1>
```

But its not loading in the browser .I am getting error Error: $compile:tpload
Error Loading Template in the browser console.

Can you please tell what I am missing here?

Comment: where if `test.html`??

Comment: @Saurabh Agrawal Its in the same folder where index.js and controller.js are present

Comment: and `childCtrl`??

Comment: ``templateUrl`` should be relative to the ``index.html`` as far as I know. Meaning that if you have an ``index.html`` in your root folder and your scripts and templates are all inside ``app`` folder, the template URL should look like this - ``templateUrl: 'app/test.html'``.

Comment: It works https://plnkr.co/edit/vS0H1xF6OlzA2DsHktO8. It's probably just the file paths?

Comment: @dork ,Yeah I think so.Its not working in chrome and internet explorer but when I tried with Firefox it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like its a browser issue,It was not working in chrome and internet explorer.I tried the same code with Mozilla Firefox and it worked.

Thanks everyone for your suggestions.